# Does -Werror interfere with template correctness and/or SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-warnings

I have the feeling that this is a dumb question and I guess that the answer is a simple "No", though I have no clue how to be certain about it other than asking for your help...

**Does `-Werror` interfere with template correctness (not sure what is the right term, see example below) and/or SFINAE?**

Consider this simple contrived example:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    int a;
}

int main() {
    //int a; // error: unused variable 'a' [-Werror=unused-variable]
}
```

Uncommenting the line in `main` results in an error when compiled with `-Werror`. I know the compiler is supposed to generate an error for templates that are erroneous for any template parameter even if not instantiated. This is not the case here. I will only see the error (which is of course actually only a warning) here when I instantiate the template.

Why I ask this question: I am used to compile with `-Werror` always, hence my perception of what is a warning and what is an error is a bit blurry in some regards. Now for templates and especially SFINAE it does make a big difference if something is just a warning or really an error.

Comment: Seems to be a QoI issue. For instance, [Clang diagnoses it right away](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ed103656feb7043).

Comment: @StoryTeller hm ok, unfortunately I couldnt come up with a good SFINAE example, where it matters even more, as a wrong idea of what is an error can lead eg to the wrong overload being called

Comment: A step in the right direction would be to make `a` dependent. I.e. `int a;` --> `T a;`. Then Clang and GCC act the same.

Comment: A template which has no possible valid instantiation is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, so compiler differences wouldn't denote a bug. But in any case an unused variable is not an error according to the standard, so the question is down to QoI indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the compiler is supposed to generate an error for templates that are erroneous for any template parameter even if not instantiated.

That is not the case, though. If no instantiation can be generated for a template, then the program is ill-formed, **no diagnostic required**<sup>(1)</sup>. So the program is ill-formed regardless of whether you get an error or it compiles "successfully."

Looking at it from the other perspective, a compiler must not allow a warning-turned-error to affect SFINAE, as that could change the semantics of a valid program and would thus make the compiler non-conforming. So if a compiler wants to diagnose a warning as an error, it must do this by stopping compilation and not by introducing a substitution failure.

In other words, `-Werror` can make the compiler reject a well-formed program (that is its intended purpose, after all), but it would be a compiler bug if it changed the semantics of one.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Quoting C++17 (N4659), [temp.res] 17.6/8:

> The program is
>   ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template ... and the template is not instantiated, or
> - ...

Comment: what about SFINAE? sorry for not putting an example, maybe its a different question, but I also wonder if SWINSFINAE (subsitution warning is not SFINAE). Does SFINAE consider only hard errors and only then I'd get an warning (which becomes an error due to -Werror) after SFINAE was evaluated?

Comment: I don't think an unused variable is considered "no valid specialization can be generated"...

Comment: @user463035818 I was writing an addition; I hope it answers you.

Answer (score 1):

While it's largely a quality of implementation issue, `-Werror` can indeed (and does) interfere with SFINAE. Here is a more involved example to test it:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool foo() {
    if (false) {
        T a;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename T, typename = void> struct Check {};
template<typename T> struct Check<T, std::enable_if_t<foo<T>()>> {};

int main() {
    Check<int> c;
}
```

The line `T a;` can trigger that warning (and error), even though the branch is dead (it's dead on purpose, so that `foo` is a constexpr function mostly regardless of `T`). Now, according to the standard itself, that is a well-formed program.

But because [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb7678387e33b97b) and [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d75bfb09c9eb92c9) cause an error there, and that error is in the non-immediate context of the `Check` specialization, we get a hard error. Even though according to the standard itself this should just fall back to the primary template due to substitution failure in the immediate context only.

Comment: this might be an example of exactly what i was looking for. If I understand you correctly, SFINAE picks the more specialized specialization (because there is no error) and only then gcc reports me an error because there is a warning.

Comment: @user463035818 - We never get to SFINAE. `foo<int>` is instantiated, is rejected, and that's all she wrote. That's the point about the interference with TMP.

Comment: ah right, there is no error so also no SFINAE. Awesome, i'd like to accept both answers because only with both I was able to understand..

Comment: There's also nothing in that function template that depends on `T`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - `a` does.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yours does but the OP's doesn't :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Ah, didn't get you there. Yes the OP doesn't, so there isn't much to discuss when `a` isn't dependent, it's just ill-formed NDR like Angew points out.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why is the OP's code ill-formed? I'm not seeing it. `-Werror` compiler flag doesn't make C++ things ill-formed, does it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit that was basically what was the question about, my confusion about ill-formed `!=` gcc reports an error, hence "fixing" my example was an important part of the answer

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - It shouldn't. But like Angew reasoned, no valid specialization can be formed under that flag if `a` is non dependant (and trivially constructible/destructible).

Comment: @StoryTeller `-Werror` will make the compiler reject conforming code, which is not allowed by standard, thus the compiler is already non-conforming when this flag is passed. It doesn't make much sense to say ill-formedness IMO, that's all vendor dependent.

Comment: @StoryTeller I must be missing something. There is nothing invalid about the specialization and nothing ill-formed about the code, that I can see. The flag just makes the build abort when the compiler spits out what would otherwise be a warning. That doesn't say anything about the validity of the code. How can we call this ill-formed and talk about the standard's NDR rule? It's unrelated!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Maybe ill-formed is the wrong way to put it. The point Angew was trying to make, I think, is that those constructs, which are not ill-formed per se, can be reasoned about the same way as truly ill-formed code under `-Werror`. Anyway, I think we can all agree that rejecting valid code is complete and utter rubbish.

Comment: @StoryTeller I rather like `-Werror`. Too many people ignore warnings. It's like a strict "don't be silly" extension to C++ that strengthens its constraints; once you've fixed all the sillinesses, you still have a completely standard-compliant program and implementation! Yay

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I can't disagree with that. But I can also see it from a compiler vendor's perspective. Treating warning diagnostics differently (if building under `-Werror`) is a right PITA. That's part of the reason SFINAE is limited to the immediate context too, after all. Applying the same "special pleading" logic recursively could become intractable.